# How to edit invoice PDF format?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, invoice, pdf

I just want to add some fields in invoice `pdf` template. I found the file to edit, `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`.

I need to add my client address in the template. To do that I edited the above file and I'm getting `error`.

Please find the image here and help me to do the changes.

Please help me...

[image]

Comment: first move the address billing address and shipping address where you want by editing in invoice pdf template file $page->drawText("text",x,y); at last you can add  client address in the template.

Comment: did you get your solution???

Answer (score 1):

here are classes responcible for invoice pdf generation

`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default`

and

`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice`

you can get all detail in this files

you can rewrite those classes in your module and change accordingly

you can refer below url for more detail

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/

Comment: Hi... Inchoo is an extension and the custom value can be added through that extension. I just want to change the magento core functionality... Please help me...